# Dart Flutter "Non-nullable instance field '_isSigningIn' must be initialized." Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-signin

I'm trying to do a Google Auth operation with Dart Flutter.

I made the exact same code as in the video I watched. While it doesn't give an error in the video, it gives me an error.

My codes:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool _isSigningIn;

  GoogleSignInProvider() {
    _isSigningIn = false;
  }

  bool get isSigningIn => _isSigningIn;

  set isSigningIn(bool isSigningIn) {
    _isSigningIn = isSigningIn;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future login() async {
    isSigningIn = true;

    final user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (user == null) {
      isSigningIn = false;
      return;
    } else {
      final googleAuth = await user.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      isSigningIn = false;
    }
  }

  void logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

---

Error:

```
GoogleSignInProvider GoogleSignInProvider()
package:todolist/google_sign_in.dart

Non-nullable instance field '_isSigningIn' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.
```

[image]

What is the problem? How can I solve it? I thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Make it `late` or initialize it where you have declared it like this `late bool _isSigningIn;`

Comment: `bool _isSigningIn = false;` should do the trick, no need to do the assignment inside the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because your value is not nullable, it requires a default value

```
bool _isSigningIn; //non-nullable variable should be inialized
bool? _isSigningIn; //nullable variable and does not requires initialization
```

If you make your variable nullable you can leave it uninitialized, in other case, you should either initialize it when you define it

```
bool _isSigningIn = false;
```

or inside your constructor with a value, like this:

```
GoogleSignInProvider(this._isSigningIn);
```

There is one more option, you can also give a default value:

1. put your variable in [] and give a default value, it will be positional argument but it won't be required

See the example below:

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool _isSigningIn;
  
  GoogleSignInProvider([this._isSigningIn = false]);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the _isSigningIn either nullable or intitalize it. i.e

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool? _isSigningIn; // Note the ? (question mark).
```

**or**

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool _isSigningIn = false;
```

You are getting this error because dart now support null-safety and it's on by default. While the older version of dart don't.